# Need help, get Segmentation fault at rdmsr instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

I tried writing assembly code like this:

```
mov ecx, 0xc0000082
rdmsr
```

I tried this instruction on an old CPU, AMD Dual-Core C70 Processor, x86 Architecture. When I try to debug I get a Segmentation error in the `rdmsr` instruction.

There are solutions, tricks or what should I do? or does the `rdmsr` instruction not support x86 processors?

I read a little documentation that the instructions support older processors such as Pentium I, etc.

Comment: The Intel “Software Developer Manuals” Reference books should be consulted to answer most of the questions asked -https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html

Comment: Or this? [Root Has Segfault Executing RDMSR Assembly Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26331730/7509065)