# how to access rdmsr from c program?

Tags: c, linux, performance, intel

From intel software developer manual 3b, I came to know MSR (10H) equal to RDTSC. So I wanted to verify it using piece of code as follows in my program:

```
asm volatile("rdmsr":"=a"(lo),"=d"(hi):"c"(0x10));
```

But when I run my program it showed segmentation fault. Then a realized the caution that it work only in privilege level 0. So I run the program again with sudo access. This time the program ran without seg fault but the statement after asm volatile(..) are not getting executed. Even it dint work out.

What shall I do to make rdmsr work in my program?
(I am using linux on i7 core which supports these counters. I verified it.)

Some related posts are [Cannot read back from MSR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183654/cannot-read-back-from-msr) and [rdmsr,wrmsr from c/c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875778/execute-rdmsr-and-wrmsr-instructions-from-c-c-code)

Comment: Privilege level 0 is kernel mode. It's not root.

Answer (score 2):

You confuse CPU/hardware privileges (restrictions on instructions to execute, memory accesses) with OS/system privileges (OS functions, files, etc.). A root application does not run at a different CPU privilege level than code of a normal user. It just has more allowance for OS functions.

You have to run that instruction from the OS kernel which typically runs at ring 0.

Comment: oh, thanks @Olaf But any idea how to run it from OS kernel level.?

Comment: In order to run code at OS kernel level you can develop kernel module. Linux kernel modules run in ring 0.

Comment: @ANTHONY: As desowin wrote: If only the kernel runs in Ring 0, you apparently need a kernel module. Note that is not like a simple C program and can cause damage to hardware and filesystem, up to complete loss of data - because ring 0 allows code to do basically **anything**.

Comment: @ANTHONY: If the answer was helpful, please remember to upvote and/or accept.